# SQl query to find multiple fixtures that a user hasn’t yet predicted, but other users may have

Tags: sql

I have a football predictions database and I need a sql query that I can use to display all the fixtures that a specific user has not yet predicted. All predictions are kept in the UserPredictions table so a Left Join checking if the FixtureID is null will not work without another condition.

I have a fixtures table with FixtureID, HomeTeam, AwayTeam & FixtureStartTime as well as a UserPredictions table with UserPredictionID, UserID, FixtureID, HomeTeamPrediction & AwayTeamPrediction.

For example:
There are a total of 4 fixtures.

User 1 has predicted fixtures 1 & 2.

User 2 has only predicted fixture 2.

User 3 has predicted fixtures 1-4.

I want to get the fixtures that user 1 is yet to predict (3 & 4), but I would like to just be able to choose the UserID and the query will display outstanding predictions based on the user.

I can’t wrap my head around it.
Thanks

Comment: Please add a tag for which database platform you are using

Comment: A left join from your FixtureID table TO your UserPredicions table would work though, would it not? `SELECT F.FixtureID FROM FixtureID F LEFT OUTER JOIN UserPredictions UP ON F.FixtureID = UP.FixtureID AND UP.UserID = {inputted user id} WHERE UP.FixtureID IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists`:

```
select f.*
from fixtures f
where not exists (select 1
                  from predictions p
                  where p.FixtureID = f.FixtureID and
                        p.UserId = ?
                 );
```

The `?` is a parameter placeholder for the user you care about.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

EDIT:

```
select * from fixtures
where fixture_id NOT IN (select fixture_id from UserPredictions where user_id = 1)
```